# Error on posting back editor fields with decimals

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I get this error when I post back the fields below: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Decimal' to type 'System.String'.

The fields as part of the form:

```
<div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Donation.Amount)
    </div>    
    <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBox("Amount", string.Format("{0:f2}", Model.Donation.Amount))
    <!--  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Donation.Amount) -->
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Donation.Amount)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Pledge.PledgeTotal)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Pledge.PledgeTotal)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Pledge.PledgeTotal)
    </div>
```

Both of which are decimal properties in the model... is it trying to post back as string then? Then how do I convert it back to a decimal before post back? Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: can we see your action method ?

Comment: my mistake... see bottom comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

In your view model:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:F2}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public decimal Amount { get; set; }
```

And in your view:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Donation.Amount)
```